# BOX API, use Box javascript preview SDK to read all files in my box account

Tags: box

I'm trying to use `Javascript Preview SDK` to read all files in box account from my web application. I would like to see a preview of all files on my box account from my custom web application. There is some way to use a default `ID` that allow me to read all folders and files in the box account?

Currently, I'm trying to use:

```
Box.Preview.show('FILE_ID',{
        token: access_token,
        container: '.preview-container',
        showDownload: true
      });
```

The `access_token` is obtained through the procedures described in [this](https://docs.box.com/docs/app-users#section-3-request-an-app-user-token) page. Besides, using the code above I obtain this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I set request header using `Javascript Preview SDK`?
Thank for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the URL of your app (http://localhost:3000) to the CORS Allowed Origins text area. You can find this field in the form you used to create your application, the same form where you also obtained the Developer token. Note: Avoid the use of trailing slashes in the URL.

Comment: I'm having this issue even though I've added it, any suggestions?